# Database and thousands of short lifetime data - MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

My application needs to store thousands of data for a short period of time (1 hour) and after that I don't need them anymore. I'm wondering what's the best solution :

- create a table, store everything and keep everything
- create a table, store the data and delete them after two hours
- create a table per user, store the data and delete the table after two hours

I use PHP/MySQL. Is there an optimized way of doing that ?

Regards

Comment: store everything and keep everything? - only if there is some regulatory or legal reason to do so. Second option seems best.

Comment: But note that partitioning is a good way to easily drop old data